# Scheme: Cond "not equal"

Tags: lisp, scheme, conditional-statements

I'd like to do this in scheme:

```
if ((car l) != (car (cdr (order l))) do something
```

in particular I wrote this:

```
((eq? (car l) (car (cdr (order l))) ) 
 (cons (count (car (order l)) (order l)) 
       (count_inorder_occurrences (cdr (order l)))))
```

but it compares `(car l)` with `(car (cdr (order l))` for equality.
I want instead to do something only if `eq?` is false. How can I do that in my example?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `not` for that.

```
(cond
 ((not (eq? (car l) (cadr (order l))))
  (cons (count (car (order l)) (order l))
        (count-inorder-occurrences (cdr (order l))))
 ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not` to negate the value of a predicate.

e.g. in an `if` statement: `(if (not (eq? A B)) <EVAL-IF-NOT-EQ> <EVAL-IF-EQ>)`

or in a `cond` you can do:

```
(cond ((not (eq? A B))
       <EVAL-IF-NOT-EQ>)
      .
      .
      .
      (else <DEFAULT-VALUE>))
```

Comment: thanks to you too, I can't use "if" if not it would be simpler as you wrote

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `cond` or `if` if you don't have a list of else cases.  `when` might be what you are looking for.  It's basically just the true case of an `if`.

```
(when (not (eq? (car l) (cadr (order l))))
   (cons 
      (count (car (order l)) (order l)) 
      (count-inorder-occurrences (cdr (order l)))
   )
)
```